# What does "Etwas Belebter" mean in "Verklarte Nacht"

Tags: terminology, classical-music

In the first movement of "Verklarte Nacht" by Arnold Schoenberg there is a term "Etwas belebter". When I checked this word in dictionary it mean "Somewhat busier". When I listen to the piece in this part the piece is becoming faster. does busier here means faster?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Etwas belebter" here is used with the meaning "Somewhat more lively".  Speed is an obvious component of that but you might also make the articulation a bit more sprightly, articulating somewhat snappier and giving some more danceable weight to the natural rhythmic accents.